# window.location.href with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I need help.

If I use JSON.stringify(window.location.href), is there any way to show that URL without "" (quotes / as a string)? So showing it like a link and not a string.

If not... Is there a way to use window.location.href in React without having to use JSON.stringify()?

Or maybe use something to replace window.location.href but same result?

Basically need to show / use that url as a link (html < a >  tag) not as a string.

New images!

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4QfD.png)

[useStickyState function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7x2L.png)

--- Ignore the key: URL_HREF its MY_URL instead ---

[with JSON.stringify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XilJv.png)

[without JSON.stringify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb6eL.png)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you show  the actual code related to your problem

Comment: There you have !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do what you're asking.

```js
class SimpleExample extends React.Component {
  
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
        <a href={`${window.location.href}`}> Link </a>
      </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SimpleExample />, document.getElementById('example'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="example"></div>
```

**EDIT:**
But I'm also curious why `<a href={window.location.href}> Link </a>` doesn't work.

Comment: I forgot to mention that what im trying to do is to storage this window.location.href in Local Storage when i click a button. So if i go to inspect -> Application -> LocalStorage -> There I have a key called MY_URL with a value of https://my-website.com(Example). So I have a state where i store 2 things (key, window.location.href). Then Inside button i have -> onClick={event => setUrl(event.target.value)} where setUrl comes from the state, and value its that window.location.href. (value={url} its passed inside the button)

Comment: I attached images of the code

Comment: https://codepen.io/ajaymehul/pen/mdqWmGK?editors=1111

Comment: Hey, this code kinda worked. My url its changing based on the onClick event, like it has to change. In production it gives me an error tho. Error -> "The resource <URL> was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally." I dont know if you have any idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with your custom hook. Here's a variation that should work:

[TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwFBzgEwKYDMCGBXAG3hwGc4AlDHAYxgBoU48SMBhHAggIxoGsHUzDAFEsWDLQFMWAZRg4YGKTACeYDHAAiwEmAXUAFsrUaZGGHIUYAgrWAQAdgwC+cLFAgg4AcihVa3gDcSEgA9KHSGAAyMpaKAFxwACoGOnBpOHAgEGjAWMAYaHAAbhhQJPYOcBBYcCoQeFBwAERCcsDUvCpxGM0hGAAekLBwquoUGCSE8AA8SXAAvCUQwGh0cMJwg4oOaGTCUB5NSwdHAHyLyXAAPhvBSIPD8Fh4DnaOcADm5qfQcAAUg2oGDAMEqiVevAcEAA7g4AJSJX5NZCoPwwRpVIEgsEfYAOEjyN4YGobQ5-AD8WwGwNBlTgiQcGBhZKO-zkUHxn0BNJxlXh8OCzn6Q2g8DGGgAUiQPksuBAIAQqFVbg5CAQbnA1SAuGVNYTOQ5PprpY4ANoAXU1CDgZt4GBUiQNXItiVNVWcwUeYtGJjg7oAahxVgo-kt-mgFDg3TKEYsLvLFcr7t6Ri83riqiQcOIAAo4coaObUnZ7f2xy7us7-ABWsadMENn3WxWDkYS5ccQYIIZgYYB8PjoygeAwiImUyIcwuqOHKkQjFQ1EchPQUcrMgA8gA5AB0ekLtdjg9IyWCqFQeQBrZ77YwEajArg6Mxa-k54vMAMHhZTJZyP+bx80LIpJS3bc3BwYAlSKG9e0qbxBUYYUl30AwAUGQcbRfKAqm+GAAMwwI4GFYUHlFNNXneLMc2iGQAHFzDgYttgwXYyHdStY2re1HTgZ0jRbNsrBjLthL7Y4ByHRtR3HShJxgacFyXFd4DrWU4AICBqA4ORoBwb5d3wgBJRQQH+XjBwpKk-1ZaB-gAAy0nSCD0qADI0YAzLgBQWgAEgQXjnGaOAYVPNVOAcpC0XMV91KqfFCRwYlSWROAqXihl+No4CWCPRwhNvKwkLI1NniozNsvEGIzFmeZWPYzsqiWKsLIdBsm0K0dEiSOTJmmZS50GlSCTUisWvA3cBM+PIVH+G9ZI-VBnN0iSPKm8xTIwczePWeLopIxgdJgQwMIGLDn1i3Cvh+ckoB5QVDtKijyozekhBq+RFGY+qBlLDjuP+Rh8S81aROSKReI6rkpDgu8KVEhxu17aAGHHM0ko7JJ1hYCwvowRJtF0NCZlqnpbEzaczitWdl1G20FqUfjzG7UcrSWNp8f+EH5Fc-GkMYIRRHEWh-n+QcFhnRc4Dp1cDxYIolmzaqGPMac2pUQrezHJb0lqf55cKdJRuS4FUrurDQgAKlGAwNBWvn9O+EoOFHULwvVOArdCFCLwwAgWGZmBWfvQ20AO5x1jtB0tbvC0BZG1dcZiEPLiEdhOB4ToZiJvQToMUnzHJ6iqerGhKsl4a9YBCVSXL+kFkbnx02oxCq9QXGQ4NvxiiHWcLwvWX4EZy568cbuMGKA6B8T+Aykk5W6NqjWup1uBwjgSAdjBDgCHnIQXg1LA-kwLg8E+GajWlgecKqRnddQZxp4vW-dbIgeh5dgg3aWMeHF1zurt7yM2fp-eelxF41XMCvL+i114RC3mxHenB94sEPm4E+GAz4Xy5MhKOu0g4h3jvcGKGJrpmkZjjcwKcgEWiFCEMIERhADBwOAJU0gPLxBCJ-AOABpB0lxvAAFkACaAB9AAquQKIQQQgt0qsw1hYB2HdwgGAEgiQbReW2mIxoBBoZGhIlhI6qlbRgB7vYZge9WA9k6IUCRUACBUJgLmCxDQSDWNsfaNADiCDs0iJ9Kw-wYT4jQLCXcK1My7m-NgdYfCHQJxlqYgwyU0BKhsR0XgiRKDl13EI9xIhSgOBgAACVSUqKAMwSlJCEVEawbwDDQGEEqEASCLhLEnn3aWG9XGTyQVqBQwBSgDOKMAT4gyPgfGoF46Wk99w9yQZobA+AiDixIReDeEiwB3ltvbbSq0naeTMtLXGvTRnuM8Zk+xjjgmhPCZEyo0S-BYESagDe24cCjPGd9PsuytTMjgFIqI0sQm7HufsqJMTahLHMWokgu5tEgF0Y4j8noQikNfEDAeMxcjFDONfZiuKzhnMsWQIFmjzGT1JZcuxPjHHOBmKEIlBKZg4AJagKFCwECwvUQisyyKCC+xntUBwGTOhcpSbsdJXihUXjONyjwvLEUCoZaEHA+LsVMqGRquAJUkBAA)

> If you aren't using or can't use TypeScript in your React project, you can navigate to the playground link above and copy the transpiled JavaScript code (it's on the right side of the page).

```ts
import {
  default as React,
  useCallback,
  useEffect,
  useState,
  type Dispatch,
  type SetStateAction,
} from 'react';

// useLSState: This is a modified version of your "useStickyState"

export type Result <T = void, E extends Error = Error> = T | E;

export function getError (exception: unknown): Error {
  return exception instanceof Error ? exception : new Error(String(exception));
}

export type Json = boolean | null | number | string | Json[] | { [key: string]: Json };
export type JsonValidator = (data: Json) => boolean;

export function safeParse <T extends Json = Json>(json: string, validate: JsonValidator = () => true): Result<T> {
  try {
    const data = JSON.parse(json) as T;
    if (validate(data)) return data;
    throw new Error('Parsed JSON failed validation');
  }
  catch (ex) { return getError(ex); }
}

export function safeLSGet <T extends Json = Json>(key: string, validate: JsonValidator = () => true): Result<T> {
  const json = localStorage.getItem(key) ?? new Error(`localStorage item at "${key}" was null`);
  return json instanceof Error ? json : safeParse(json, validate);
}

export function safeLSSet <T extends Json = Json>(key: string, value: T): Result {
  try {
    const json = JSON.stringify(value);
    localStorage.setItem(key, json);
  }
  catch (ex) { return getError(ex); }
}

export function useLSState <T extends Json>(
  initalState: T,
  key: string,
  validate?: JsonValidator,
): [state: T, setState: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>] {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initalState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const parsed = safeLSGet<T>(key, validate);
    if (parsed instanceof Error) {/* the localStorage value was null */}
    else setValue(parsed);
  }, [key, validate]);

  const setLSValue = useCallback<Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>>(action => {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
      setValue(prev => {
        const value = action(prev);
        const err = safeLSSet(key, value); // potentially useful for debugging
        return value;
      });
      return;
    }

    const value = action;
    setValue(value);
    const err = safeLSSet(key, value); // potentially useful for debugging
  }, [key, setValue]);

  return [value, setLSValue];
}


// Example usage:

const lsKey = 'MY_URL';

function Example (props: { item_url: string }) {
  const [previouslyClickedUrl, setPreviouslyClickedUrl] = useLSState(window.location.href, lsKey);

  const handleClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLAnchorElement> = ev => {
    // Prevent native navigation on click
    ev.preventDefault();

    // Update the localStorage item
    setPreviouslyClickedUrl(window.location.href);

    // Navigate to the new URL
    window.location.href = props.item_url;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Previous URL: {previouslyClickedUrl}</div>
      <a
        href={props.item_url}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >{props.item_url}</a>
    </div>
  );
}
```